# Unable to override a method from child class in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, overriding

I'm trying to self teach scala. I was trying to implement Inheritance and stumbled upon a small issue. Can somebody help me with it?

Question:

1. In the code below, why am I unable to set value for x for objects p6, p7 and p8.
2. Why am I unable to override the def setX in my child class?

```
object classes {
    def main (args: Array[String]) {
        //create objects for class Point
        val p1 = new Point
        println("P1 created using no argument constructor: "+p1.toString())

        val p2 = new Point
        p2.setX(1)
        println("P2 created using setter methods: "+p2.toString())

        val p3 = new Point(2)
        println("P3 created using single argument constructor: "+p3.toString())

        val p4 = new Point(3,1)
        //demonstrating how to use objects within println statement
        println(s"P4 is created using default constructor and its x value is ${p4.getX} its y value is ${p4.getY} and its id is ${p4.id}")

        val p5 = new ThreeD
        println("P5 is created using no argument constructor of 3D class: "+p5.toString)

        val p6 = new ThreeD(2)
        println("P6 is created using single argument constructor of 3D class: "+p6.toString)

        val p7 = new ThreeD(2,3)
        println("P7 is created using two argument constructor of 3D class: "+p7.toString)

        val p8 = new ThreeD(2,3,4)
        p8.setX(5) // has no effect.. why??
        println("P8 is created using default constructor of 3D class: "+p8.toString)
    }

    //The class name works as a class constructor which can take a number of parameters.
    class Point (var x: Int, var y: Int) {
        //demonstrating how to protect the values
        this.setX(x)

        /*
        Scala does not have static methods or static variables.
        However we can mimic its behavior. 

        Outside the scope of the class, create a companion object for the class
        Companion objects has same name as that of the class and holds the static members and functions.
        */

        val id = Point.getId

        //lets define getters and setters
        def getX() : Int = x
        def getY() : Int = y

        def setX(x: Int) {
            this.x = x
        }

        //this is how we override a function
        //here we implement our custom toString() method
        override def toString() : String = {
            return "(%d, %d) and id is %d".format(this.x, this.y, this.id)
        }

        //lets define other constructors

        //to define a constructor, we create a method called "this"
        //constructor with no arguments
        def this () {
            this(0,0)
        }

        //constructor with 1 value
        def this (x: Int) {
            this(0,0)
            this.setX(x)
        }


    }

    object Point {
        //static member
        private var id = 0

        //static method
        private def getId () : Int = { id += 1; id}
    }

    //Inheritance
    class ThreeD (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Point (x, y) {
        def this(x: Int, y: Int) {
            this(0,y,0)
            this.setX(x)
        }

        def this(x: Int) {
            this(0,0,0)
            this.setX(x)
        }

        def this() {
            this(0,0,0)
        }

        //to override parent class's setX method
        override def setX(x: Int) {
            super.setX(x)
        }

        override def toString() : String = {
            return "(%d, %d, %d) and id is %d".format(this.x, this.y, this.z, this.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a lot about Scala case classes, immutability and trait. I would suggest you get a good book or tutorial about thesz topics

Comment: Yes @cchantep I agree. I guess the tutorial that I was following isn't quite helping me. Clearly I'm missing a lot of the details. Can you suggest good books or point me to some nice docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class ThreeD (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) extends Point (x, y)` 
does *not* declare a class with three members. `x`, `y`, and `z` are *not* members of class ThreeD, they are just constructor arguments. (You would have do declare them as `(val x: Int, val y: Int, val z: Int)` if you wanted them to be members ... or rather `(override var x: Int, override var y: Int, val z: Int)` in this case ... but *don't do this* - see below).

Because in scala, class constructor is pretty much the whole body of the class, it is sometimes hard to tell the difference: you can reference constructor parameters anywhere inside the class body as if they were members.

It only begins to matter, when the members are mutable (not a good thing in general, you *don't* want to have mutable members as a matter of policy).
Here:

```
override def toString() : String = {
  return "(%d, %d, %d) and id is %d".format(this.x, this.y, this.z, this.id)
}
```

`x`, `y`, and `z` refer to to the constructor parameters, *not* the overridden members of `Point`.  `p8.setX` call *does* change the value of member `x` of `p8`, but it is not what `p8.toString` prints - it prints the value of the constructor argument, which is `2`.

The take away from this:

1. Avoid using mutable members. You very rarely need that in scala. If you think you need it ... think again.
2. Don't give constructor arguments same names as the members they initialize, especially, if you plan to access them within the class body.  If you do, declare them as `override val x`, not just `x`.

Comment: Couple of things I observed  

1. The parent class members and child class members has to be same name. Otherwise scala complaints it is unable to find the variable  
2. I'm unable to override the member in the child class within constructor  

`class ThreeD (override var a: Int, override var b: Int, c: Int) extends Point (a, b) {`  

I get the following error  

`error: overriding variable a in class Point of type Int;
 value a cannot override a mutable variable`

Comment: 1. I don't know what you mean by "have to be the same name". You can most certainly have class members with different names :)
2. Indeed, you cannot override `var`s, because it does not make any sense: it is mutable, and it would have to be the same type anyway, so, overriding it would have exactly the same effect as simply assigning a different value to it.